# Does having a custom update query with WHERE clause gives more performance while updating in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have an entity called Car . Now the entity's primary key is not an auto generated Id. Lets say I need to update my car entity with a set of values.But the problem is I am having a requirement of ensuring the given Id is already existing in the database. Because I know in spring Data JPA we use the `save()` method to both save and update an existing entity.

Then in a case of inserting a new primary key for the `save()` method will lead to a save otherwise it will update that specific entity.So I always need to ensure during the update that the method will not create new entities for invalid ids.

So to overcome this issue I have seen many developers use a `find()` method call before the updation to ensure the given primary key is already existing.But you can see there will be an additional database hit to ensure that.

So to overcome this issue I thought of going with a custom update query.Then I can determine if the query is executed or not by declaring it's return type as int in the JPARepository. So according to my knowledge query will output 1 for success and 0 for a failed updation.

So what I need to know is, in the case of providing a not existing primary key for the method `updateCar()` can I always ensure that the update doesn't succeed because of that invalid primary key. I mean what happens if the update fails due to a different error?

The ultimate goal of this discussion is to avoid the check of the existence of the primary key before the updation. So if there any better approach please state it.

Ex:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Car c SET c.status =:status WHERE c.id =:id")
    int updateCar(@Param("status") String status, @Param("id") String id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The int you get back from the update is the number of rows updated.

> So what I need to know is, in the case of providing a not existing
> primary key for the method updateCar() can I always ensure that the
> update doesn't succeed because of that invalid primary key. I mean
> what happens if the update fails due to a different error?

If the update fails for any other reason then you will get an Exception.

The problem with your solution is that you will have to write update statements for every use case.

Comment: You are 100 percent right , I analysed the behaviour with the aid of application log.I saw the query throwing exceptions for the cases like constraint violations.So is there any way to write dynamic jpql queries to overcome this issue.I mean I have written dynamic where queries like ```SELECT  d FROM DbpTAndC d WHERE (:termStatus is null or d.termStatus= :termStatus ) AND (:termType is null or d.termType=:termType) AND (:termVersion is null or d.termVersion=:termVersion)"``` in my application.Is there a way to do the same with update.

Comment: If I make an assumption that I cannot write dynamic update queries ,  I guess still in a case of updating a specific column in an entity still my suggestion is better. I mean if we have a method which use always one column to be update during it's process , when it comes to performance even though we have to write an additional query , I guess my suggestion is better.I am I correct ?

Comment: If you want to write your own select, insert and update queries you may have a look at http://jooq.org/ Hibernate is create to use entities and not create sql

Comment: I guess JPQL and HQL are there to full fill that requirement. Cant we achieve dynamic updation through those languages like I already implemented to select.

Comment: You would have to write CASE statements in the update

Comment: Can't it be done like the dydnamic select statement which I shared with you .Because in that JPQL select statement I have implemented a dynamic where clause by neglecting the null values .So query is intelligent enough to filter the values from the database by searching under the attributes which are not null in the where clause.  For an example if the termStatus is null then termStatus won't add up to the search Criteria.```:termStatus is null or d.termStatus= :termStatus``` .So I am asking that can't we do the same to the Update statement by setting only the attributes which are not null.

Comment: But you want to have a dynamic update clause not the where clause. So no

Comment: Yep I thought there will be a way to do the same after the set keyword.So the query can only update the attributes which are passed as not null to the method parameters.

Comment: That's what case would be for.